# Ошибки при сборке ruby под Windows

Tags: ruby, компиляция, сборка

Вывод:

```
ffi.c
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(215) : e
rror C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(578) : e
rror C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(579) : e
rror C2065: 'sz' : undeclared identifier
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(579) : e
rror C2065: 'sz' : undeclared identifier
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(724) : e
rror C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ffi_prep_closure_loc'
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(724) : e
rror C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(724) : e
rror C2059: syntax error : 'type'
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(866) : e
rror C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(867) : e
rror C2065: 'sz' : undeclared identifier
C:/Users/Aydar/Desktop/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1/src/x86/ffi.c(867) : e
rror C2065: 'sz' : undeclared identifier
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BI
N\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BI
N\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: ох ты боже мой, это же виндоус! Зачем тебе понадобилось собирать из сорцов? Для мастдая есть готовый RubyInstaller

Comment: Зачем тебе понадобилось собирать из сорцов? 
Версия новее

Comment: @Aydar2015, а зачем тебе версия новее? Она не нужна тебе.

Answer (score 1):

ОМГ!
Для винды используй http://railsinstaller.org/en

Packages included are
Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.1
Bundler
Git
Sqlite
TinyTDS
SQL Server Support
DevKit

Comment: З.Ы. поставь виртуалку с убунту или минтом - сэкономишь себе КУЧУ нервов.